# Find the Index of the First Occurrence in a String

Tags: python

currently practicing some leetcode questions.
I was trying to solve the following:

Q:"Given two strings needle and haystack, return the index of the first occurrence of needle in haystack, or -1 if needle is not part of haystack."

My answer is as follows:

```
class Solution(object):
    def strStr(self, haystack, needle):
        """
        :type haystack: str
        :type needle: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        if needle in haystack:
            for i in range(0,len(haystack) - len(needle),1):
                if needle in haystack[i:i+len(needle)]:
                    return int(i)
        else:
            return -1
```

The error I got:

```
TypeError: None is not valid value for the expected return type integer
    raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type integer");
Line 42 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 48 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Would very much like an explanation why is it..

Comment: `i` is already an integer, there's no need to use `int(i)`.

Comment: `if needle in haystack[i:i+len(needle)]:` should be `if needle == haystack[i:i+len(needle)]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the chosen range of len(haystack) - len(needle) is [off by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

This leads to situations where despite `needle in haystack` is `True`, the loop index `i` cannot reach the needle (e.g. haystack = "xy", needle = "y"). In that case, the for loop runs through without success and, after having completed the whole function, `None` is returned (the return type is apparently checked by leetcode and this triggers the Exception you see).

Hence, changing `len(haystack) - len(needle)` to `len(haystack) - len(needle) + 1` solves the issue. Or (again, as pointed out in the comments) just use [`return haystack.find(needle)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find).